# Applescript: Logging System Event in an "If/else" statement? Possible?

Tags: applescript

In Applescript it possible to log inside an If/Else statement?

```
set x to 20
log "Log something"

if 10 > x then
    return "10 is greater than " & x
    log "something else"
else
    return "10 is not greater than " & x
    log "something else still"

end if
```

In the example above, the Event logs "Log something", but neither of the other logs inside the if/else statement, even though the conditions are met and the 'return' works.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The `return`-statement let the script immediately leave and return the value. The `log`-statements are not executing ;-)
Just change the order and log before returning :-)

Enjoy,
Michael / Hamburg

Comment: Thanks @ShooTerKo  That fixed this example but in my actual source code it is still not working.  Is it different when you have nested if/else statements?

Comment: No... Instead of returning you could set a variable's value. In your example you could write `set returnValue to "something else"` etc. At the end of your script or handler use `return returnValue`. So your script or handler will always run till the end! More help is difficult without more information about your code. Maybe your problems are something completely different like logic errors in if/else...!?

Comment: It's all good now. I was trying to log to console inside an "tell application". It wasn't working. I just created a variable inside the tell application, then logged the variable after the end tell!